# Can plugging a monitor in a video port affect performance speed of a Windows 7 PC (HP Compaq 600 microtower)

Tags: video

Can running a second monitor through a video port socket in my Windows 7 PC (HP Compaq 600 microtower) slow down the computer? The machine didn't have a second monitor socket and the cheaper purchase was the video port socket converter for the screen to plug in there.

Comment: Just to note, I can't seem to find any reference to a compaq 600 - could it be a compaq 6000?

Answer (score 3):

Any increased load will cause a performance degeneration. Whether or not you will notice it is another question.

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking no, but there's no obvious way i can see (unless it was a VGA/Mirroring cable - which just outputs the same signal to both outputs) that you can 'just' double up VGA ports that you have - in which case there will be no additional load on the system. If you're using a USB-> VGA adaptor, there may be some additional processor load (and those have trouble handling full motion video in most cases anyhow).

Neither of these should be significant, unless the system is struggling with the tasks its handling already.